# Understanding step four in the excision theorem (Hatcher - algebraic topology).

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, simplex

I'm studing the proof of the excision theorem (Proposition 2.21 p119) in Hatcher's book (freely available on [https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)). This proof gives four steps. In the fourth step, on p123, we consider the following fragment.

[image]

I guess here $S^m(\Delta^n)$ refers to the operator $S$ constructed in the second step. I can see that if we consider $S^m(\Delta^n)$ for large enough $m$, then every simplex that occurs in its decomposition has image contained in some $\sigma^{-1}(U_j)$.

Why does it follow that $S^m(\sigma)$ is in $C_n^\mathcal{U}(X)$? Maybe we have the relation $S^m(\sigma) = \sigma_\sharp(S^m(\Delta^n))?$ (I can't prove this). Any help on the matter will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On p. 122 Hatcher defines

> (3) Barycentric Subdivision of General Chains. Define $S : C_n(X) \to C_n(X)$ by setting $S(\sigma) = \sigma_\sharp(S(\Delta^n))$ for a singular $n$-simplex $\sigma : \Delta^n \to X$.

Thus $S$ is defined on the generators of $C_n(X)$; this extends uniquely to a group homomorphism.

As you guess correctly, we have $S^m(\sigma) = \sigma_\sharp(S^m(\Delta^n))$, but this is not completely obvious.

The first problem is that Hatcher does not explicitly define $S(\Delta^n)$. He only explains what the barycentric subdivision of $\Delta^n$ is (it is a simplicial complex consisting of "smaller" $n$-simplices contained in $\Delta^n$ and all their faces). In "(2) Barycentric Subdivision of Linear Chains" he introduces the subdivision homomorphism $S : LC_n(Y) \to LC_n(Y)$. The missing ingredient is this: Take $Y = \Delta^n$ and define $$S(\Delta^n)  = S(id_{\Delta^n}) . \tag{1}$$
This is a linear $n$-chain in $\Delta^n$.

The next problem is that Hatcher misses to show that for each $\lambda \in LC_n(Y)$ the subdivision homomorphism $S$ satisfies
$$S(\lambda) = \lambda_\sharp(S(id_{\Delta^n})) = \lambda_\sharp(S(\Delta^n)).\tag{2}$$
Note that on the LHS of $(2)$ we use $S : LC_n(Y) \to LC_n(Y)$ and on the RHS we use $S : LC_n(\Delta^n) \to LC_n(\Delta^n)$. I do not prove this here, you can do it using the inductive formula $S(λ) = b_λ(S∂λ)$. Clearly $(2)$ is the minimal requirement in order that
$$S(\sigma) = \sigma_\sharp(S(\Delta^n)) \tag{3}$$
is *well-defined for all $\sigma \in C_n(X)$.*

Once we know that $(2)$ is true, we can easily prove that for $\lambda \in LC_n(\Delta^n)$ and $\sigma \in C_n(X)$
$$S (\sigma_\sharp (\lambda)) = \sigma_\sharp (S(\lambda)) . \tag{4}$$
In fact, we have $S (\sigma_\sharp (\lambda)) = S(\sigma \lambda) = (\sigma \lambda)_\sharp(S(\Delta^n)) = \sigma_\sharp(\lambda_\sharp(S(\Delta^n))) = \sigma_\sharp (S(\lambda))$.

But $(4)$ shows that on $LC_n(\Delta^n)$ we have
$$S \sigma_\sharp = \sigma_\sharp S .\tag{5}$$

By induction we now easily get $S^m(\sigma) = \sigma_\sharp(S^m(\Delta^n))$. In the proof note that $S^m(\Delta^n) \in LC_n(\Delta^n)$ for all $m$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad it turns out to not be trivial. It was clear from context for me what $S(\Delta^n)$ was, because we have $\Delta^n = [e_0, \dots, e_n]$ so we can view this as a linear chain. In $(2)$, are you sure that what you write is correct? It looks trivial given (1).

Comment: @user839372 Yes, it is correct. These second equation in $(2)$ is of course trivial, but the first equation needs to be proved. It is a special case of $(3)$, but for linear $\lambda$ it can be proved, whereas $(3)$ is a definition generalizing $(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll go over your answer in detail and will get back to you. It sure is a complicated proof for me!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was clear to me. Maybe one follow up question: Would the following be correct: For $m$ sufficiently large, $S^m(\Delta^n)$ is a signed sum of simplices with image contained in some $\sigma^{-1}(U) $ where $U \in \mathcal{U}$, and thus $S^n(\sigma) = \sigma_\sharp(S^m(\Delta^n))$ is a signed sum of simplices contained in some $\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(U))\subseteq U\in \mathcal{U}$, from which we deduce $S^m(\sigma) \in C_n^{\mathcal{U}}(X)$? I.e. the claim that I wanted to prove is really necessary to deduce the claim in Hatcher's proof.

Comment: @user839372 Yes, that is the point. Iterated barycentric subdivision produces "small" singular simplices having images in elements of the given cover.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I understood the logic behind the proof. Thanks again and have a nice day :) !

Comment: If you are interested, here is a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171983/stuck-in-the-proof-of-the-excision-theorem-hatcher